# Rails: display create form from one model into another model view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, action, conventions

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I am not a seasoned Rails developer.

From what I understand, the Rails way of doing things is:

- Create a model.
- Create a controller for this model, with actions such as create, show, etc.
- Render these actions through a related view with a corresponding name, such as new.html.erb, show.html.erb, etc.
- Route the view to the desired URL with the router.

What I don't understand though, is whether or not we can mix two models with each other.

For instance, in our app, we have a User model, a Calendar model and a Post model.

A user has many calendars and a calendar has many posts.

And we need to allow people to:

- Create a new @calendar from their profile (users#show).
- Create a new @post from a calendar.

The way we accomplished this was by:

- Creating a `_calendar_form.html.erb` form and include it into our user's `show.html.erb`.
- Creating a `_post_form.html.erb` form and include it into our calendar's `show.html.erb`.

However, we are not sure this is the right / Rails way of doing things and feel like we may be breaking the MVC pattern.

If that is the case, is there a solution to achieve a similar result, but with a more conventional approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a calendar from user profile, you'd first need to define `@calendar` in your `UsersController` show action.

```
def show
  @calendar = Calendar.new
end
```

In your form, you can use `@calendar`, Its same as calling `form_for Calendar.new`

```
= form_for @calendar do |f| 
  = hidden_field_tag "user_id", @user.id # passing in user_id as a param
```

Now in your `create` action in `CalendarsController` you can use the `user_id` params to make calendar belong_to the user.

```
def create
  calendar = Calendar.new(calendar_params)
  calendar.user_id = params[:calendar][:user_id]
  calendar.save
end
```

You can also use accept nested_attributes, but the above might explain how MVC and association works. Follow the same approach for the other model. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's acceptable put a form anywhere, but usually make sure to submit your form to the right endpoint. If `calendar` and `post` are in different forms, you would expect to have them posted to `CalendarsController` and `PostsController`.

The exception to this is usually when you have a `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in your model. Eg. if `class Calendar` had `accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts`, you would be able to have `CalendarsController` do `Calendar.new(posts: {description: 'Foo'})` and both the calendar and post would be saved at once.

It helps me to first think of REST actions (think your calendar form posting to `/calendars`, etc.), and the controllers just being a proxy for what you could do on a command-line with the models (create model records, etc.). This approach also makes you think of "fat model/thin controller" and abstract as much as you can within your model.